# Prove by induction the inequality $2^{n!}>n^n$ for $n>2$

Tags: inequality, induction, exponential-function, factorial

My attempt so far:

Base case:

$2^{3!}>3^{3}$

$2^6 > 27$

$64> 27$

Then going for

$2^{(n+1)!} > (n+1)^{(n+1)}$

I get

$(2^{(n!)})^{(n+1)} > (n+1)^{(n+1)}$

Since n+1 is positive,

$2^{n!} > n+1$

And I do not go where to go from here. I am unsure if I am following the correct path. Am I approaching this in the correct way?

Comment: You know $2^{n!}>n^n,$ so you just need $n^n>n+1.$

Answer (score 3):

We're trying to prove $2^{n!} > n^n$. You've shown that the base case holds - great.

In an induction proof you assume that the statement holds for an arbitrary $k$, and then you have to show it holds for $k+1$ *dependent* on it holding for $k$.

$2^{(k+1)!} = 2^{(k+1)k!} = (2^{k!})^{k+1}$

Now we have to remember that we're assuming that the statement holds for $k$, ie we assume $2^{k!} > k^k$. Also we clearly have $k^k > k+1$. Putting these two inequalities together and raising to the $k+1$'th power we get

$$(2^{k!})^{k+1} > (k^k)^{k+1} > (k+1)^{k+1}$$

and so

$$2^{(k+1)!} > (k+1)^{k+1}$$

which concludes the proof.

Essentially we prove that if it's true for a certain $k$, then it will also be true of $k+1$ and since you yourself showed that it's true for the lowest $n$ in the set you're considering, it must be the case that it's true for any integer higher then that $n$.

Comment: great, I got it thanks

Comment: "clearly have $k^k > k +1$".  Is it necessary to prove this?  I realize it's very 'obviously' true when $k > 3$.  Sorry for the ignorance.

Comment: I think proving that might be a little pedantic

Comment: well that can be very easy to prove with induction regardless, but I don't think it is necessary personally

Comment: $k^k > k +1$ is "clear" indeed, without induction: $k^k > k^2 > k +1$.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially the solution above is right. I'll give the same but with an extra.

**BC (Base case)**

You've already proven this.

**IH (Induction Hypothesis)**

Suppose for some integer $m \ge 3$ that

$$ 2^{m!} > m^{m}$$

You can notice now, that

$$ 2^{m!} > m^{m} > m+m > m+1 $$

And thus, $2^{m!} > m+1 $. Finally, if we raise both sides to the power $ m+1$ , we get.

$$ 2^{(m+1)!} > (m+1)^{m+1} $$

Which of course will hold for every integer $m$.

$\blacksquare$